# android trafficstat per application since application installation or a certain time frame

Tags: android

i need to retrieve the amount of bytes uploaded and downloaded for my app between a time frame and not only since device boot (same as when you go to settings and display data usage of an app).
currently i am retrieving the amount only from the last boot.

here is my code :

```
         final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

            ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
     for (int i = 0; i < appProcesses.size(); i++) 
     {
                Log.d("Executed app", "Application executed : " + appProcesses.get(i).processName + "\t\t ID: " + appProcesses.get(i).pid + "");
                ApplicationInfo app = null;
                try {
                    app = pm.getApplicationInfo(appProcesses.get(i).processName, 0);

                        long delta_rx = TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(app.uid) ;

                        long delta_tx = TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(app.uid) ;

                    Log.d("Executed app", "delta_rx : " + delta_rx + "\t\t delta_tx: " + delta_tx + "");

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
```